# Can I insert a quote in my Q from documentation which is not free?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I wanted to quote a chunk of the documentation which is not free (for instance, ISO standards is not free). Can I do it?

Comment: Depends on the license of the source. Some sources are not free, but you are free to reference it. Stackoverlow and it's license don't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Under the doctrine of *fair use* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) you may, subject to jurisdiction, have a defence against actions for breach of copyright.  Or you may not.

Comment: This is definitely fair use. You are sharing a limited amount of the original for educational purposes. You're covered, as long as you clearly attribute it back to the original source. Moreover, it is done all the time with the C and C++ standards.