# Quoting from documentation of GPL code in questions & answers

Tags: discussion, licensing

Recently, [this question about posting GPL code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287986/posting-gpl-code-in-an-answer) made me wonder about the implication for SO posts containing quotes from documentation of GPL code.

I'd assume that as an element released with the GPL software that it could qualify as covered work unless otherwise explicitly released under a different license, such as the [GFDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html). In either case (GPL or GFDL), the documentation would be under a license that is incompatible with the cc-by-sa license used on SO.

Now the GPL license acknowledges fair use, a mention which is echoed in some meta posts (e.g. comments [this other question about non-free documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270326/2994596)). Is quoting from documentation inherently more a case of fair use than posting annotated snippets of GPL code?

If it isn't, what are the available alternatives for questions requesting clarifications about GPL code documentation, and for substantiating answers with documentation references? Are we expected to paraphrase as best as we can, leaving only external references to the actual documentation?

Comment: Quoting from the docs is very likely to be fair use.

Comment: You might want to consider asking a lawyer for answers to legal questions.

Comment: My thought is that we should relax the "code must be in the question" rules if you provide a link to the code (as long as it's easy to find on the linked page and follows the other rules, such as being text instead of an image, etc.). That way you can link to GPL'd code on GitHub (for example) if you have a question about it.